# Magento 2 Customer registration mail to admin

Tags: magento, magento2

I've been playing around with Magento 2 for the last couple of weeks and have managed to get several things to work. The only thing I am struggling with right now is sending a mail to the admin once a customer has registered.

What I am looking for is something like:
If (mail has been sent to customer confirming registration) {
send mail to admin}

Hopefully this is enough.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The steps to send Email to admin after customer registration in Magento 2**

Create events.xml file in \app\code\Namespace_Modulename\etc\frontend\ and add following code. Here, we need to define an event for Send mail after customer registration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="sendmail_toadmin" instance="Namespace\module_name \Observer\SendMailToAdmin"/>
</event>
</config>
```

Create SendMailToAdmin.php file in \app\code\Namespace_Modulename\Observer. This observer class is used to send mail after customer is registered successfully.

```
namespace Namespace_Modulename\Custom\Observer; 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 
class SendMailToAdmin implements ObserverInterface
{

const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'trans_email/ident_general/email';
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $inlineTranslation;
protected $scopeConfig;
protected $storeManager;
protected $_escaper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
) {
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{


    $customer = $observer->getData('customer');

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try 
    {
        $error = false;

        $sender = [
            'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstName()),
            'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($customer->getEmail()),
        ];
        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($sender);
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
        $transport = 
            $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('1') // Send the ID of Email template which is created in Admin panel
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // using frontend area to get the template file
                'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage(); ;
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();


    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) 
    {
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. 
Sadly I am unable to make the code you've given to work. 
I assume that I am supposed to structure the folders like \app\code\MyNamespace_Mymodulename\etc\frontend 
and 
MyNamespace_Mymodulename\Observer 

I also edited the code to match my folders like:
instance="MyNamespace\Mymodule_name \Observer\SendMailToAdmin"/>
and
namespace Mynamespace_MyModulename\Custom\Observer;

Comment: Have you followed the magento 2 module standard for implementing this code ?

Comment: Managed to fix my problem, didn't name the module and it's content properly. The code you've given works now. Thanks!